# Error with oci_connect()

Tags: php, oracle11g

I'm trying to connect my PHP page to an Oracle Database but I keep getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in

So I downloaded the Instant Client from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html),
but I keep getting the same error.

[Here](https://app.box.com/s/salec4vr9m6dvg7h8bpd6026edqu94ch) is my PHP info.

I'm using IIS and I can't use Apache.

Please help!

Comment: check php_oci8.dll this file in php/ext folder

Comment: or you restrat you APACHE ????

Answer (score 1):

You need to restart `IIS` after adding the Instance Client Package.

After restart, must check the `php_oci8.dll` file in php/ext directory.

And one last thing, disable `extension=php_oracle.dll` from your `php.ini` file, its an old and deprecated Oracle extension.

Comment: thank you for your response , can you explain step by step please in-order for me to follow and I'm using IIS not Apache

Comment: @Glory: oh i am sorry mate, yes i can guide you, first of after downloaidng restart it, and second step chk phpinfo();, if you found your package its fine, else, check .dll file in php/ext ..... and check extention in php.ini is it disable or not....

Comment: I installed it following the instruction at this link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZDDI9HFBIU , and when I check the PHP manger I find orci8 enabled but when I run phpinfo() I can't find it :( do you know what I did wrong? thank you

Comment: this official link will help you must check the point 5 and 10: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-084410.html @Glory

Comment: thank you so much , I did find the package (OCI8) when I load phpinfo and search for it I can find it but I'm still getting the same error ! and I tried to follow the steps at the link you provided but I couldn't find  mod_fcgid.so and mod_fcgid.pdb files. I really appreciate your help thank you